# Standard Java varargs converter to array

Tags: java, arrays, methods, variadic-functions

My question is quite simple.

Is there a method in core Java that does the following code:

```
<T> T[] asArray(T... values) {
    return values;
}
```

I tried looking for it in **Arrays** class, but there seems to be no such method.

To give you a context:

The previous person who worked on this code decided that varargs is better than regular array in class constructor (even though it IS supposed to be an array). Right now I have to add another generic array as the last parameter of the constructor thus transforming this code:

```
public Clazz(String... values) {
}
```

to this

```
public <T> Clazz(String[] values, T[] additionalParameters)
```

As a result I need to refactor all places where this constructor was used. What is worse that there is a couple other classes that follow the same pattern and I need to be modify them sometime in the future. And that is where above mentioned method *asArray* could help.

I know that it is better to just replace varargs with explicit array creation in every occurrence (and that is what I am going to do anyway), but I still want to know if there is such method already (just out of mere curiosity).

Comment: In Java 8+, you might do `return (T[]) Stream.of(values).toArray();` and in earlier version `return Arrays.asList(values).toArray(values);`.

Comment: Note that generic array types (such as `T[]`) have [limited support](http://stackoverflow.com/q/529085/113632) and are a common source of bugs. You'd be wise to use a `List<T>` instead.

Comment: Well, you could also just create your array an equal it to `T...` values. `T[] tArray = values;`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can do:

```
T[] a = Stream.of(t1, t2, t3).toArray();
```

Comment: Yeah, that is an interesting solution. I don't know why I didn't think about it myself. :)

Comment: This first constructs an array (from the varargs), which is passed into a new `ArraySpliterator`, which is then passed into a new `Stream`, which then allocates a second array (in `.toArray()`), which it then copies in linear time from the original array into a new `Node` via at least one additional linear `copyInto()`, before finally returning an array. Multiple array copies and numerous object allocations, for what benefit?

Comment: @dimo414 On a varargs? I'd be surprised if it contains more than 10 elements! Write clean code instead of thinking of 10 elements array allocation.

Comment: You'll really want to use the overloaded `toArray` method here. In which case, you probably should've just generated the array yourself.

Comment: @JeanLogeart I'm not sure I understand your point, this *isn't* clean code.

Comment: @dimo414 This is clean code to me. Just not a clean problem :)

Comment: -1 again.  This will a) fail to compile, because the array's of the wrong type; b) it's longer than just creating the array as in dimo's answer.

Answer (score 10):

The JDK doesn't need to provide such a method since you get the same behavior by simply constructing an array - e.g.:

```
// these two statements are conceptually identical
String[] a = asArray("a", "b", "c");
String[] b = new String[]{"a", "b", "c"};
```

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned that. I just wanted to know if there some standard way. :)

Comment: The array constructor *is* the standard way.

Comment: Can't argue with that. :)

Comment: The syntax is noisy and un-ergonomic, even by Java standards.